# How to set the x axis dynamically in High Charts 2.3.5

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to dynamically set the X axis rotation in Highcharts 2.3.5, but when the chart is redrawn the X axis remains unchanged.

By following the documentation I was able to set the rotation as the chart is constructed but I need to be able to set the rotation after that in response to other events on the page. Unfortunately I cannot update to the latest version of Highcharts in order to to this, and must remain using 2.3.5.

I am currently using this method:

```
chart.xAxis[0].options.labels.rotation = degrees;
chart.redraw();
```

This does seem to change the rotation value within the highcharts object but upon redrawing the chart nothing has actually changed.

Does anybody know of any way to do this without updating to the latest version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you at least update to next version after 2.3.5? It's 3.0.0 version. Since then updating axis is supported via `axis.update()`. Otherwise, you will need to find workarounds for all things. Like setting `axis.isDirty = true` etc.

Answer (score 0):

instead of that you can use chart.xAxis.update() method.

here is a link for its api documentation http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Officially `axis.update()` is available since 3.0.0.